# ASP.NET MVC controller and routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller called `AccountController` which handles user-related actions.
I also defined a method:

```
//
// GET: /Account/Login
public ActionResult Login(string token)
{
    //logic here
}
```

Why the following URL without `token` specified would invoke the above action?
`http://localhost/Account/Login`

I would expect URL like `http://localhost/Account/Login?token=abcdefgh` invoke the action ONLY.

This is my routing config:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I'm new to ASP.NET MVC. Can you suggest me how to do? I have updated my routing config above. Please see.

Answer (score 0):

As Login action `GET` http request type
`http://localhost/Account/Login` matches action name works and pass null value to `token` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does kind of seem weird. Since C# has a nullable type, it would be nice if it accepted null when I specify `string? token` and forced me to specify a value when I specify `string token`.

That is why I like the new attribute based routing which exactly has that behavior. It has been bundled into the latest version of Web API. If you are using the old version still, you can use this Nuget package - http://attributerouting.net/

To force the user to specify token, you would write

```
[GET("account/token"]
public ActionResult Login(string token)
{
    //logic here
}
```

To make it optional, you would write

```
[GET("account/token?"]
public ActionResult Login(string token)
{
    //logic here
}
```